# JMeter loop variables

Tags: jmeter

I have test case in Jmeter (2.5.1).
I need to define a variable and then change its value in a while loop, basically:

```
isQuest = true;
while(${isQuest}){
     Http Sampler
         Reg Exp Extractor -> set the isQuest based on the result
}
```

Because JMeter loads the User defined variables to the memory once at the beginning, it doesn't let me assign another value to the variable in the memory.

What is the best way of overcoming this issue?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

You may use jmeter properties instead of variables, accessed via [jmeter functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or beanshell code:

```
${__P(whileCondition,)}
${__setProperty(whileCondition,TRUE,)}
${__BeanShell(props.get("whileCondition")}
${__BeanShell(props.set("whileCondition")}
```

You may try to use something like the following construction:

```
Thread Group
    HTTP Request
    //set-found-condition
    ${__setProperty(txtFound,FALSE,)}
    While Controller
    // invert value in condition - will be executed while txtFound == FALSE
    Condition = ${__BeanShell(!props.get("txtFound")}
        . . .
        [execute your test logic here]
        . . .
        YOUR HTTP Request
            Response Assertion
            // set your text assertion here
            // this will results in ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} = TRUE if text found
        IF Controller    --FOUND
        // if text found set separate variable or property - e.g. ${txtFound} - into TRUE
        Condition = ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
            HTTP Request 
            //set-found-condition
            ${__setProperty(txtFound,TRUE,)}  // this will be inverted to FALSE in the next WHILE cycle's condition, WHILE cycle will be exited
        . . .
```

I think you may also easily use BSF or BeanShell PostProcessor attached to **YOUR HTTP Request** to set txtFound property into TRUE instead of cumbersome construction with IF.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can assign value to user defined variable in runtime. If you use BeanShell PreProcessor, `vars.put("variablename", "variablevalue");`